# Why would SQL Server sort operator reduce row estimate?

Tags: sql, sql-execution-plan

The execution plan for the following query (produced by nhibernate) shows that the sort operator is reducing the number of rows after the sort operation. What could cause this? The query performance is improved by using a hash join hint for the left outer joins however due to the wrong estimates SQL is using a Nested Loop instead. I am wondering if the sort operator is causing this some how.

```
SELECT TOP (26)  
col_0_0_,  
col_1_0_,  
col_2_0_,  
col_3_0_  
FROM (  
    select   
    table0.table_id as col_0_0_,  
    propertyst2_.dataTypeString as col_1_0_,  
    propertyst3_.dataTypeString as col_2_0_,  
    propertyst4_.dataTypeString as col_3_0_ ,  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY propertyst2_.dataTypeString) as __hibernate_sort_row  
    from dbo.Tables table0   
    left outer join dbo.PropertyDataString propertyst2_ on table0.table_id=propertyst2_.parent_id and (propertyst2_.propertyType_id='p0') 
    left outer join dbo.PropertyDataString propertyst3_ on table0.table_id=propertyst3_.parent_id and (propertyst3_.propertyType_id='p1') 
    left outer join dbo.PropertyDataString propertyst4_ on table0.table_id=propertyst4_.parent_id and (propertyst4_.propertyType_id='p2') 
    where table0.tableType_id='p3' 
) as query 
WHERE query.__hibernate_sort_row > 221052 ORDER BY query.__hibernate_sort_row
```

[image]

Comment: what about date of statistic on this tables?

Comment: I have updated the statistics multiple times and also added covering indexes (this is on a dev server)

Comment: Probably it is the effect of the `top 26` Row goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem in my query and I confirm that this is due to TOP N.
SQL Server expects to use just k*N first rows from Sort operation, but the next filters shows that those rows are excluded, so it takes more rows, that's why we see Actual Number of rows that is much higher than expected after sort operation.

Comment: We upgraded to SQL 2014 which supports OFFSET and ROWS FETCH which seemed to get better estimates. (@Martin Smith if you add an answer I can mark it as accepted since that was the initial hint for us to look at OFFSET. Otherwise I'l mark this as the answer)

Comment: @masdude BTW We decided to move some logic to UDF that returns table of Id's. OFFSET and ROWS FETCH wasn't the option as the probem appears in query generated by EF and we use SQL Server version starting from 2008 R2 depending on customer.